# using laravel with another application in a sub directory

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I have a laravel instance on a domain:

laravel-instance.com

I want to be able to run another application on the same domain:

laravel-instance.com/app2

app2 is a vanilla php app, but laravel is blocking the app. Is there a way that I can create an htaccess rule or tell laravel to ignore /app2?

Comment: This should just work if you create a folder within your public folder called `app2` and add your application in there. Have you actually tried this?

Comment: yes its there, but when I try and navigate there I get the laravel based 'whoops page not found error' which I guess means that laravel is somehow picking up on the http request and then checking againts its routes.

Comment: Within that folder is there an index.php file?